# How do I make a div align on screen accounting for the width of the scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, center

If I make a div align in the center of the screen using the JavaScript window.innerwidth property, the div centers perfectly according to the pixel width on the screen. However, if I align another div (as a fixed navigation bar) by making its width 100% and putting a margin on its left and right, it centers according to the pixels in the screen WITHOUT the scrollbar. Of course, when both divs are on the same page, you can clearly see they are not aligned the same way. I guess the best way to combat this is to make the original div element center on the screen (with JavaScript) accounting for the scrollbar's width. How may I go about this? Do I need to access the scrollbar's width, and, if so, how?

Thanks in advance.

[Result Illustrated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zDSt.png)

Comment: Do you have a minimum working example of this? Maybe you could create one on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you trying to disable the horizontal scroll?

Comment: So, when I centered one div on the page (using CSS width: 100%; margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;) it centered right in the middle of the part of the screen that does not include the space of the scrollbar. When I centered another div (using JavaScript this time, with window.innerWidth which is the entire length of the page, including the width of the scrollbar), it centered it in the middle of the entire page, including the scrollbar, while the original CSS method is the length of the page minus the scrollbar for some reason. I was wondering how I could make the JS-centered div center like the CSS?

Comment: Ok, here is a [JSFiddle I made](http://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/bootstrap). Is this a solution to your problem? It uses some basic CSS from bootstrap.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't ever edit this JSFiddle I made in the answer as I intended to. https://jsfiddle.net/jambuzz06/tL9pgsxf/12/ In it you can see the fixed navigation bar is not centered with the div below, which makes it feel very unnatural, as it is centering based on the width of the non-scroll width of the screen, while the script I made to center the content div uses the width of the entire screen. Thanks for your input, I'll have to see tomorrow.

Comment: James, from what I see on your JSFiddle, it seems to be working as expected (nav centered in middle of screen). One thing I would suggest doing is try to not use javascript for this if you can avoid it. Something you might find helpful is the [bootstrap framework](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) (or at least the grid system used in it). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: The project I have requires the centering script. I updated the original answer with an image illustrating the problem. On JSFiddle, unless it's just my computer or browser for some strange reason, you can clearly see how the body div is cut off by the scrollbar, b/c it is centering itself relative to the whole page; the scrollbar is added on, over the div. The navigation div, on the other hand, is centering itself relative to the part of the page minus the scrollbar f.s.r. I need to accommodate for this in the JS to get both divs to align relative to the part of the screen w/o the scrollbar.